# JPanel from another class wont appear in main JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

This is my main frame code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainGUI extends JFrame {

    cPanel cP = new cPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainGUI main = new MainGUI();
        main.setVisible(true);
    }

    private MainGUI(){
        setTitle("X");
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        add(cP);
    }   


}
```

Then my JPanel code

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class cPanel extends JPanel{

//cPanel
    JPanel cP1 = new JPanel();

//Panel 1
    JLabel lb1 = new JLabel("dx");
    JLabel lb1dx = new JLabel("dx (pixel)");
    JTextField tf1dx = new JTextField(5);
    JLabel lb1dy = new JLabel("dy (pixel)");
    JTextField tf1dy = new JTextField(5);
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("move");


    public void cPanel(){
        setBounds(0, 0, 600, 190);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 8));
        add(cP1);

    //Panel 1   
        cP1.add(lb1);
        cP1.add(lb1dx);
        cP1.add(tf1dx);
        tf1dx.setText("10");
        cP1.add(lb1dy);
        cP1.add(tf1dy);
        tf1dy.setText("10");
        cP1.add(btn1);
    }

}
```

The Panel doesn't seem to appear. The frame appeared with the title and no size, adding `pack()` to the frame does nothing. I've tried a lot of ways including making a new class to try, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: get rid of `setLayout(null);`

Comment: Tried. Still the same

Comment: Just to be clear, `cPanel` is not a subclass of `MainGUI` (but it is a subclass of `JPanel`).

Comment: Use getContentPane().add on the JFrame .

Comment: Tried adding under main or MainGUI(), nothing works.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void cPanel(){ //get rid of void as it is a constructor not a method.
//public cPanel(){ instead
    setBounds(0, 0, 600, 190);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 8));
    add(cP1);
```

```
private MainGUI(){
    setTitle("X");
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null); //change this to setSize(500, 200) or something.
    add(cP);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because of the wrong implementation of the cPanel class. You have created a method in  cPanel class rather then constructor. The constructor must not have a return type, make the below changes and it should work.

```
public cPanel(){
    setBounds(0, 0, 600, 190);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 8));
    add(cP1);

//Panel 1   
    cP1.add(lb1);
    cP1.add(lb1dx);
    cP1.add(tf1dx);
    tf1dx.setText("10");
    cP1.add(lb1dy);
    cP1.add(tf1dy);
    tf1dy.setText("10");
    cP1.add(btn1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As Berger suggests: use getContentPane()

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainGUI extends JFrame {

cPanel cP = new cPanel();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainGUI main = new MainGUI();
    main.setVisible(true);
}

private MainGUI(){
    setTitle("X");
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800,600);
    getContentPane().add(cP);
}
```

}